# How to have a button with CSS and Javascript classes in a layout

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, button

Is it possible to have button in layout which is HTML and have CSS style and some Java-script classes.

For example :

[image]

this button comes with some CSS and some Js. So how is possible to have CSS and Js with HTML content in a layout?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the WebView in your layout
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

```
String summary = "<html><body>Your html content.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: OooKay..It was useful but my HTML body is big and when i add to the code it mixed up with rest of the code..So what's the solution. also is there any way to address CSS and Js file?